# Reutilizar codigo del controlador Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, controller

mi pregunta es acerca de una duda que me surgió al estar trabajando con Laravel me di cuenta de que estaba repitiendo mucho mi código en el controlador lo cual me lleva a preguntarme si de alguna manera puedo reutilizar este códigos en diferentes funciones para no estar escribiendo el mismo código les pongo mi ejemplo.

```
      public function store(StoreTabulatorRequest $request)
                 {
                      $tabulatorHistory = new CatTabulatorHistory();
                      $tabulatorHistory->name = $request->input('name');
                      $tabulatorHistory->cat_contract_type_id = $request->input('cat_contract_type_id');
                      $tabulatorHistory->start_date = $request->input('start_date');
                      $tabulatorHistory->end_date = $request->input('end_date');
                      $tabulatorHistory->date_active = now();
                      $tabulatorHistory->save();
                    
                }
     public function update(Request $request, $id)
        {
            
               $tabulatorHistory = new CatTabulatorHistory();
               $tabulatorHistory->name = $request->input('name');
               $tabulatorHistory->cat_contract_type_id = $request->input('cat_contract_type_id');
               $tabulatorHistory->start_date = $request->input('start_date');
               $tabulatorHistory->end_date = $request->input('end_date');
               $tabulatorHistory->date_active = now();
               $tabulatorHistory->save();
        }
```

Lo que estoy haciendo es crear un history de mis tabuladores el código está incompleto claro, solo agregue lo referente a mi duda y es que en las dos funciones creo una nueva instancia para agregar un registro en mi tabla de history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes usar los Traits de php, podrías llamarlo: TabulatorTrait en el directorio

```
\App\Http\Traits
```

te debería quedar algo como:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Traits;

use \App\CatTabulatorHistory; // donde tengas el modelo
trait TabulatorTrait {
    
    public static function CatTabulatorHistory($data, $id): {
        $tabulatorHistory = new CatTabulatorHistory();
        $tabulatorHistory->name =$data['name'];
        $tabulatorHistory->cat_contract_type_id =$data['cat_contract_type_id'];
        $tabulatorHistory->start_date =$data['start_date'];
        $tabulatorHistory->end_date =$data['end_date'];
        $tabulatorHistory->date_active = now();
        $tabulatorHistory->save();
    }
}
```

después de eso puedes importar el trait donde tu quieras y lo único que tienes que hacer es pasarle la data o el id y ya

Comment: Muchas gracias @BetaM por la aclaración, efectivamente son de php y no de laravel.